# Create input field by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I trying to add an input field whenever I click a button.
It works, but it doesn't matter which button I press all of the containers get this input, I want to make a button that works on each container.
Maybe I need to create another component for that or there is a solution that will work on my "Main" component without open another?
{Can use only React and JS I know there is a way in jquery}
I Got 4 divs of PRODUCT so I meant that the button will trigger each one separately
My code :

```js
function Products(props){
    function FunctionClick(){
        let myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
        for(let i=0;i<myContainer.length;i++){
            let myInput=document.createElement('input');
            myContainer[i].appendChild(myInput)
        }
        
    };
    

    return(
    <div className='container' id='Container'>
    <span className='namestyle'>{props.name}</span>
    <span className='descriptionstyle'>{props.description}</span>
    <span className='descriptionstyle1'>{props.description1}</span>
    <img className='imgstyle' src={props.img}></img>
    <span className='pricestyle'>{props.price}</span>
    <span className='ratingstyle'>{props.rating}</span>
    <button onClick={FunctionClick} id='plusbut' className='plusbutton'>+</button>


    </div>)

}

export default Products;
```

EDIT-
Sorry if you didn't realize what I am trying to achieve I hope this will make it better-
I try to make each button operate its own div.                                              Now when I clicking on one button all of the divs get an input field and I want that the button will trigger only the div I clicked on.
Thank you, guys.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? I struggle to figure it out from your question

Comment: Sorry for that, I try to make each button operate its own div.                                              Now when I clicking on one button all of the divs get an input field and I want that the button will trigger only the div I clicked on.

Comment: But what should happen eventually? each click does? summon a new div? fetch input value? aggregate values?

Comment: w.r.t your last comment - do you mean you have few instances of "Products" ?

Comment: Yes, I got 4 divs of product on my APP component. sorry for the misunderstanding I will edit now.

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you're trying to do, but I can tell you straight out that when using react you really don't want to manipulate the DOM directly. Render react components instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const products = [
  { id: 1001, name: "Product-1" },
  { id: 1002, name: "Product-2" },
  { id: 1001, name: "Product-3" },
  { id: 1002, name: "Product-4" },
  { id: 1001, name: "Product-5" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Product Demo</h1>
      <Products data={products} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Products = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((v) => (
        <Product {...v} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Product = ({ id, name }) => {
  const [showInput, setVisibility] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisibility(!showInput);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container" id="Container">
      Product Name : {name}
      {showInput && (
        <div>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick} id="plusbut" className="plusbutton">
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-goldwasser-yjxil?file=/src/App.js:0-1033

Please let me know if your use case is different/or facing any issues.

Comment: Working great my friend thank you for your time.                                                                              This code is out of my league

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you query the elements.
When using `document.getElementsByClassName` you query the whole DOM thus, given a few instances that use divs with the same class - you'll fetch them all.

What you'd like to achieve, basically, is a component that scopes its actions.
Something like this should do the work:

```js
function Product(props){
    let renderInputField = false;
  
    function onClick(){
        renderInputField = true;
    };
    
      return(
      <div className='container'>
        { renderInputField ? '<input type="text" value={props.value} />' : ''}
        <span className='namestyle'>{props.name}</span>
        <span className='descriptionstyle'>{props.description}</span>
        <span className='descriptionstyle1'>{props.description1}</span>
        <img className='imgstyle' src={props.img}></img>
        <span className='pricestyle'>{props.price}</span>
        <span className='ratingstyle'>{props.rating}</span>
        <button onClick={onClick} id='plusbut' className='plusbutton'>+</button>
      </div>
      )
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Not woking, the syntax is wrong, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not a linter ;) 
Make the relevant fixes, but point is that you need a conditional _scoped_ code injection logic

Comment: Can't figure out what's wrong here its look as you wrote it fine but it's still screaming at me O_o thank you Aviad.

Comment: @Oded I fixed the example above, try again please :)

Comment: Still the same Aviad, its seems the function onClick not working.